# preg_match multiple IP's?

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm using preg_match to match a referring url AND and an IP block. How do I tell my code to look for the referral, then if it matchs check multiple IP blocks? ie: 70.x.x.x OR 96.x.x.x

Here is my code so far (that works with one IP block "70.x.x.x")

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ((preg_match("/referrer-domain.com/",$referrer)) && (!preg_match("/70./",$visitor))){
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://www.new-domain.com'>";
}
?>
```

I know this is a simple question, just having a brain fart today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match("/(70|96)./",$visitor)
```

It should also probably be:

```
preg_match("/^(70|96)\./",$visitor)
```

or you'll be blocking 1.2.96.4 and 1.2.3.70 etc. as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using regular expressions' "alternation" syntax, which is basically an OR operator. You will also need to anchor the expression to the beginning of string using "^", which will ensure that you're matching against the first octet of the IP, and a backslash to escape the dot, which is a wildcard in regular expressions.

This snippet should work for you:

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if ((preg_match("/referrer-domain.com/",$referrer)) && (!preg_match("/^(?:70|96)\./",$visitor))){
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://www.new-domain.com'>";
}
?>
```

You may also want to consider just using PHP's header() function instead of a meta refresh, i.e.:

```
if ((preg_match("/referrer-domain.com/",$referrer)) && (!preg_match("/^(?:70|96)\./",$visitor))){
    header("Location: http://www.new-domain.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate and arguably better, solution is to use the php's ip2long() function.

That turns a dotted IP address into an integer, and you can do your comparisons using > and < logic.

eg.

```
ipstart = sprintf("%u", ip2long('70.0.0.0'));
ipend = sprintf("%u", ip2long('70.255.255.255'));
$visitor = sprintf("%u", ip2long($visitor = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
$referrer = sprintf("%u", ip2long($visitor = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));

if (($visitor < $ipstart | $visitor < $ipend) | ($referer < $ipstart | $referer < $ipend) ){
     header('location: http://www.new-domain.com');
}
```

If $ipstart and $ipend were arrays of valid IP ranges you could iterate over them to check any number of different IP ranges.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php for why the use of sprintf is important, and for some other things to watch out for with partial IP addresses, etc.